# Multi-Threading in Database lookup

Tags: pentaho, etl, pdi

I've a question about the multi-threading in a database lookup. I need to increment the process rec/sec, when I look for the surrogate key.
I don't know if is possible to do this with a multi-threading in Database lookup step.

The dimension are a vertica and the origin data is a mysql 5.6 percona with galera  (3 nodes).

[sample ETL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M372Y.png)

Comment: Where are your bottle necks? You can try to load the entire database with `Load all data from table`.  You can also try adding number of steps, like you suggest, and see what kind of throughput you get then.

Comment: @sowe, what do you mean by surrogate key? Can you provide any example? A screenshot of your transformation is definitely not enough